# Pip behind a proxy with a custom certificate file

Tags: python, proxy, pip

Proxy settings for pip can be specified via the `--proxy` command line option or in the global configuration file (that is `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf` in Unix,  `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf` in OS X, `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini` in Windows).

```
[global]
proxy = [proxy server url]
```

However, while a custom root certificate file can be passed with the `--cert` command line option, there does not seem to be a way to specify a custom root certificate in the configuration file.

Specifying `cert = [path to cert file]` in the above global configuration does not seem to be taken into account, unlike the command line option.

How can we globally set up pip to use a certain certificate file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

we're behind a proxy and need the cert too. Make sure the cert file is in a place that cmd and pip (windows) would have access to. My cert is just called b.pem

I created the folder (which didn't exist already) called:

```
C:\Users\<username>\appdata\Roaming\pip
```

and added the file pip.ini to it to that folder. then in pip.ini

```
[global]
cert = C:\users\<username>\b.pem
```

I also just tested adding the the pip.ini file to:

```
C:\Users\<username>\pip
```

which, by the way, was a folder that was already created -- and this works too. Might want to give both a shot and see which works. Also, sounds dumb but make sure your path in pip.ini is correct. I had a typo the first time i did this and it drove me insane for a bit haha. good luck !

Comment: `%appdata%` = `C:\Users\<username>\appdata\Roaming`