# How to stop pip overwriting its cacert.pem file on upgrade

Tags: python, ssl, pip, virtualenv

I'm stuck behind a company firewall and to let pip through it I add some certificates to `lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem`. I noticed that on upgrade it overwrites this file with a different certificate bundle. Is there something I can set to stop this behavior? I'm running on Mac OS X

I'm running pip inside a virtualenv. If there's some way I can specify a certificate bundle for the whole virtualenv that would be best as I occasionally run into issues like this for other programs too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip behind a proxy with a custom certificate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032780/pip-behind-a-proxy-with-a-custom-certificate-file)

Comment: That answer would solve the problem of getting through the firewall, but my question is phrased specifically as how to stop pip from overwriting the `cacert.pem` file. The linked answer doesn't solve that specific problem, so in that sense my question isn't a duplicate. What's the convention here? Should this be marked duplicate?