# Any way to import python libraries without pip install?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, installation, pip

Due to employer's restrictions I couldn't use `pip install` nor the automatic installment in PyCharm on my office laptop. Both of this ways return error like:
`SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')`

Before few months I found a workaround - just to disable the VPN during the library's installation and that worked for a while, but after some time they pushed an Windows update which forbid this method too.

If I have Pandas library successfully installed on my laptop, is there any way how to export it to another machine (under the same installation restrictions)?

Comment: What compiler are you using for this? Does your computer support the libraries needed to install?

Comment: I think that it supports them. I'm talking about Pandas library and this library is widely distributed.

Comment: You can try the manual installation. This would help [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13270877/12552972).

Comment: You might try to import the proxy CA as trusted to make pip work. See [Pip behind a proxy with a custom certificate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032780/), [Dealing with SSL Authentication on a secure Corporate Network — pip, conda, git, npm, yarn, bower & others..](https://medium.com/@iffi33/dealing-with-ssl-authentication-on-a-secure-corporate-network-pip-conda-git-npm-yarn-bower-73e5b93fd4b2), [Conda: Using non-standard certificates](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/non-standard-certs.html).

Comment: Ask your employer, maybe? Sometimes there are good reasons for these restrictions!